# ERROR: services.db Additional property volume is not allowed

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

#solved
there a typo on volume , it must be volumes

i want to ask a question, i already created the `Dockerfile` and also `docker-compose.yaml` in my laravel tutor project, and i faced this problem after wrote all the code in the `docker-compose.yaml` in the terminal

im running `docker-compose up` in the terminal and it shows the `services.db Additional property volume is not allowed`. what should i do to solve this error. i am sorry this is my first time using docker.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    image: antoniopapa1991/admin-frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app

  backend:
    container_name: admin_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: admin
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORDK: root
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app

  db:
    container_name: admin_db
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volume:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 35th line change "volume" to "volumes"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Fix it
volume:
on
volumes:
Should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).